# tests wcf service in the browser

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, browser

I can't invoke a basic wcf web method in the browser even with `<ServiceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>` in the config file.

For the source, code, it's very basic:

For the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string GetData();

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: ajoutez vos opérations de service ici
    }
```

And for the implementation:

```
 public string GetData()
        {
            return ("{'code':'yes'}");
        }
```

This method works fine in the built-in visual studio wcf service tester and returns `{'code':'yes'}`.

In the browser, when I call the `http://localhost:54421/Service1.svc/GetData`, it displays a blank page. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think the problem is that browser cannot natively display JSON results - they either show nothing at all, or they show a prompt to save a file being sent back

Comment: I presume you are using the Rest Starter Kit, or have a webHttp endpoint set up?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing that by creating additional endpoint behavior for REST calls so I can have different clients. Take a look at this configuration:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

in your service definition add endpoint which is using this behavior

```
<endpoint address="/easy" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" ...
```

now you can call your service both from browser and from wcf client. To call it from browser:

```
http://localhost:54421/Service1.svc/easy/GetData
```

ServiceMetadata is for different purpose here is [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) to documentation. Basically it means your service will expose information about itself so external developers can create proxy clients.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will not display json results in browser. Generally, you will see a blank page (try viewing the source) or you will get prompted for a download.

If you are using Firefox there are some add-ons to [view JSON](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/) and the [Poster add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) for testing web services.

If you are using Google Chrome you can try [Pretty JSON](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ddngkjbldiejbheifcmnfmmfiniimbbg)