# How do I pass url in WCF REST Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am creating the following WCF REST Service:

MY Interface:

```
namespace WcfService1
{   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/InsertData/{data}")]
        string InsertData(Data data);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now how do I pass the values in the URL. If I am running the current application, the following error is coming:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885111/tests-wcf-service-in-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke InsertData method which needs complex object Data to be passed to it and you use Get method to do it. Generally it is a bad idea as Get request do not have body content to store serialized Data object - instead in Get you can pass data only as query string. For InsertData method the proper choice of http method would be Put. If you want to test your method with browser prepare method like Get(int id), specify propert UriTemplate to "data/Get/{id}" and then call from your browser yourserviceurl/Service1.svc/data/Get/1

Comment: actually i am new in wcf, i changed it back to put. Now how do i pass all values in the url?

Comment: That's a problem - if you test it with browser then you can perform only Get request :) To use other methods you would need to use some specific client. So, as I said, to test it prepare simple method that accept no parameter or only simple type parameters like int, bool, string - then you may get them from url string that you type in your browser. Try implementing Get(int id) method first as I suggested and test it.

Comment: Then it is time to prepare a client for your service. It will allow you as well to test it. I highly doubt that your service is meant to be used with browser calling it via url typed by user :) There is as well microsoft client prepared for that. Open in VS your svc.cs file and then start debug of your service - then it should automatically start this test client. Inside it you should be able to call that other method. You might as well write some js client for that with jquery ajax method for instance.